# React PrivateRoute Redirect too fast

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, routes, react-router

When user log in to the application everything is fine, but after reloading the application user is not yet authenticated and it redirect to `/login` page too fast.

Let me show you the code:

**Redux**

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: {
    user: {},
    isUserLoggedIn: null,
    isLoading: true,
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(me.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true
      })
      .addCase(me.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.user = action.payload.userData
        state.isUserLoggedIn = true
        state.isLoading = false
      })
      .addCase(me.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false
        state.isUserLoggedIn = false
      })
  },
})

export const me = createAsyncThunk('auth/me', async ({}, thunkAPI) => {
  try {
    const user = await userService.getUserData()
    return { userData: user.data.data }
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) ||
      error.message ||
      error.toString()
    thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message)
    return message
  }
})
```

**PrivateRoute**

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { isLoading, isUserLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.auth)

  if (isLoading) return null 

  return isUserLoggedIn ? (
    children
  ) : (
    <Navigate
      to='/login'
      replace
    />
  )
}
```

**App**

```
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { isUserLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.auth)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isUserLoggedIn === null) {
      dispatch(me())
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div data-theme={theme}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AppRoutes />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

To summarise the problem -> When the user reload the page -> then goes endpoint to check if the user should receive proper component, but when we received the response then already we are redirected to `/login`

How could we write it to get the best performance? Best!

**Update**

More files:

**Store**

```
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import authReducer from '../features/auth/authSlice'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({ serializableCheck: false }),
})
```

**Index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

This is probably everything :)

Comment: Do you have any sort of Redux state persistence? Can you share how you are configuring/initializing the store?

Comment: I am also curious, maybe I am doing here something wrong? Is there a better way to make it? With better performance or something?  Best!